# Which pressure to use with function that returns the water vapor entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics

I work with one old report, they calculate the specific entropy of the water vapor here using the saturation pressure multiplied by relative humidity:

[image]

That seems suspicious for me because thus the total entropy depends on the mass of the vapor twice,
also if I get the same specific entropy by temperature I have the  2.04512341809703 
and the same number I get if I get that entropy by full steam pressure (0.459732913019073 lbf/in2 )

The function description just says "pressure":

Public Function entropySatVapPW(pressure)

' specific entropy of saturated steam as a function of pressure

' entropySatVapPW in kJ/(kg K)

' pressure in bar

so I am not sure now what exactly should be there.

Comment: Is the calculation being done in the saturated steam tables or the superheated steam tables?

Comment: I use the Water97_v13.xla that "is an Add-In for MS Excel which provides a set of functions for calculating thermodynamic and transport properties of water and steam using the industrial standard IAPWS-IF97" and for 0.418356950847357 lbf/in2 I get the 2.05321910445556 - similar to their result. They say they use ""subroutine on our computer which calculates the equivalent of the International Steam Tables using ASME equations" I think it is saturated steam tables because there was not any mention of "superheated" in the text.

Comment: To get the change in entropy from the saturation vapor pressure at 77 F to the partial pressure at 77 F and 70% humidity, you can use $$\Delta S=-R\ln{0.7}$$ per mole.  See how that compares with what you get from the interpolation..

Comment: This equation gives $\Delta S=0.0394\ \frac{Btu}{lb_m-degree\ R}$, so the correct specific entropy should be 2.0451 + 0.0394 = 2.0845 $\frac{Btu}{lb_m-degree\ R}$. It looks like the calculation in your book was wrong.

Comment: Could you explain full logic behind these calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mixture of air and water vapor at these temperatures and pressures behaves essentially as an ideal gas.  For an ideal gas mixture, according to Gibbs' theorem, the specific entropy of a component in the mixture is the same as that for the pure component at the same temperature and at its partial pressure in the mixture.  The change in entropy (per mole) of a pure ideal gas between $(T_1,P_1)$ and $(T_2,P_2)$ is given by $$\Delta S=C_p\ln{\left(\frac{T_2}{T_1}\right)}-R\ln{\left(\frac{P_2}{P_1}\right)}$$So, if $T_1=T_2=(460+77)\ degrees\ R$, $P_1=0.4597\ psi$, and $P_2=(0.7)(0.4597)\ psi$, then the change in entropy between the saturated water vapor at 77 F and the superheated water vapor at 77 F and 0.4182 psi is $$\Delta S=-R\ln{0.7}=0.7087\ \frac{cal}{mole-K}=0.0394\ \frac{Btu}{lb_m-degree R}$$If I add this to the specific entropy of the saturated water vapor at 77 F, I get 2.0845 $\frac{Btu}{lb_m-degree R}$

Comment: Thank you very much, is there similar magic for enthalpy?

Comment: In the ideal gas region, enthalpy is a function only of temperature, and there is no enthalpy change upon mixing.  So the specific enthalpy of the superheated water vapor in the air at 77F and the lower partial pressure is the same as that of saturated pure water vapor at 77F.